# Failed to parse message data, when executing AT+QCFG commands via ssh session

Tags: linux, bash, sh, at-command

I am currently trying to parse data from a Linux server via ssh to another device.

I'm trying to parse some AT+QCFG commands, but I am getting "Failed to parse message data".

My command looks like this.:

```
ssh user@host ubus call modem at_cmd '{"cmd":"AT+QCFG=\"nwscanmode\""}'|grep scan
```

I hope that someone in here have experience with these types of commands.

I am very thankful for any help I can get.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

You want the `python` tool run on the distant host to receive the `{"cmd":"AT+QCFG=\"nwscanmode\""}` JSON data.

This means you want the distant host to run a command with the `'{"cmd":"AT+QCFG=\"nwscanmode\""}'` argument, where enclosing in single quotes avoid interpretation of the double-quotes or escape sequences.

This means you want to run your `ssh` command with `"'{\"cmd\":\"AT+QCFG=\\\"nwscanmode\\\"\"}'"` or `\''{"cmd":"AT+QCFG=\"nwscanmode\""}'\'` as argument, both of which will be interpreted by your local machine into the string you want the distant host to run.

You will probably want to search for another way to specify this configuration; maybe you can transmit the JSON data as a file first then refer to this file in the command you'll run through ssh?